# External file for sourcemap

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I am new to sourcemapping, but I am asked to save sourcemap in an external file, but so far I have managed to concat the sourcemap to the minified .js file. What should I add or take out from this? Or maybe I have got this completely wrong..

```
return gulp.src(sourceFiles)
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(concat('minifiedJS.min.js'))
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationFolder))
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried? Error messages? Wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps#write-external-source-map-files) for `gulp-sourcemaps`:

> To write external source map files, pass a path relative to the destination to `sourcemaps.write()`.

Try passing the current directory (`.`) as the target path for the source maps.

```
return gulp.src(sourceFiles)
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(concat('minifiedJS.min.js'))
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationFolder))
```